# Compare two different arrays and save matched record in another array in Java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, matching

I need to compare two `arrays` and when records match then save mached record to another array

```
Array1 =

[ { "phId": 10, "value": "[PACKNAME]" }, { "phId": 11, "value": "[PACKTYPE]" }, { "phId": 12, "value": "[BALANCE]" }, { "phId": 17, "value": "[DURATION]" } ] 

Array2 =

[ "[PACKNAME]", "[BALANCE]" ]


Matched Record Saved Array
[ { "phId": 10, "value": "[PACKNAME]" }, { "phId": 12, "value": "[BALANCE]" } ]
```

How can I achive this approch using javascript.

I could do matching and save array for same kind of arrays using below code but I'm unable to do above scenario.

```
let firstArray = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
let secondArray = ["Three", "Four"];

let map = {};
firstArray.forEach(i => map[i] = false);
secondArray.forEach(i => map[i] === false && (map[i] = true));
let jsonArray = Object.keys(map).map(k => ({ name: k, matched: map[k] }))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `filter` usecase:

```js
let array1 = [ { "phId": 10, "value": "[PACKNAME]" }, { "phId": 11, "value": "[PACKTYPE]" }, { "phId": 12, "value": "[BALANCE]" }, { "phId": 17, "value": "[DURATION]" } ];

let array2 = [ "[PACKNAME]", "[BALANCE]" ];

let array3 = array1.filter((el) => array2.includes(el.value));

console.log(array3);
```

More about [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: If `array2` contains a lot of items, It can be interesting to define a Set and to check with `Set.prototype.has()` instead of `Array.prototype.includes()`.

Comment: yes, to reduce loopin complexity

Answer (score 0):

You don't want all items = you don't want `map`.
You want some items that match a condition = you want `filter`.

try this:

```js
var Array1 = [
  {"phId": 10, "value": "[PACKNAME]"},
  {"phId": 11, "value": "[PACKTYPE]"},
  {"phId": 12, "value": "[BALANCE]"},
  {"phId": 17, "value": "[DURATION]"}
];
var Array2 = ["[PACKNAME]", "[BALANCE]"];

var MatchedRecordSavedArray = Array1.filter(item => Array2.includes(item.value));

console.log(MatchedRecordSavedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do: you can just filter the first array for elements whose `value` exists in the second array, as follows:

```js
const firstArray = [
  { "phId": 10, "value": "[PACKNAME]" },
  { "phId": 11, "value": "[PACKTYPE]" },
  { "phId": 12, "value": "[BALANCE]" },
  { "phId": 17, "value": "[DURATION]" }
] 

const secondArray = [ "[PACKNAME]", "[BALANCE]" ]

const matchedArray = firstArray.filter(({ value }) => secondArray.includes(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`

```js
const arr_one = [ { "phId": 10, "value": "[PACKNAME]" }, { "phId": 11, "value": "[PACKTYPE]" }, { "phId": 12, "value": "[BALANCE]" }, { "phId": 17, "value": "[DURATION]" } ] 

const arr_two = [ "[PACKNAME]", "[BALANCE]" ]

const matched = arr_one.filter( ( item ) => arr_two.includes( item.value )  )

console.log(matched)

/*
Matched Record Saved Array
[ { "phId": 10, "value": "[PACKNAME]" }, { "phId": 12, "value": "[BALANCE]" } ]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
array1=[ { "phId": 10, "value": "[PACKNAME]" }, { "phId": 11, "value": "[PACKTYPE]" }, { "phId": 12, "value": "[BALANCE]" }, { "phId": 17, "value": "[DURATION]" } ] 
array2=[ "[PACKNAME]", "[BALANCE]" ]

res = array1.filter(o => array2.includes(o.value))
console.log(res)
```